# How to compare string which is divided in 3 group in C#.net?

Tags: c#, windows

I want to compare 3 number which are in group.

```
string first = "1.0.1";
string second = "1.0.0";
string third = "2.1.0";
string forth = "1.1.0";
```

These all are versions. I want to get highest version from this. Currently third ="2.1.0" is highest.

Can anybody suggest me shortest way? or should I do custom coding?

Comment: What approach have you tried?

Comment: How about using [SemVer](https://github.com/xyncro/semver.net)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `Version` class which is designed specially for this purpose, e.g:

```
 string first = "1.0.1";
 string second = "1.0.0"; 

 if (new Version(first) > new Version(second)) {
    ...
 }
```

in your case

```
  // "2.1.0"
  String biggest = new String[] { 
      first, second, third, forth }
    .Max(item => new Version(item))
    .ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the [`Version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type? This implements the `IComparable` interface, so if you have a collection of them you can use a LINQ expression to get the largest value.

```
Version first = new Version(1, 0, 1);
Version second = new Version(1, 0, 0);
Version third = new Version(2, 1, 0);
Version fourth = new Version(1, 1, 0);

List<Version> versions = new List<Version>() { first, second, third, fourth };
Version maximumVersion = versions.Max(); // returns the 'third' object
```

Comment: Version has also a string constructor. Apart from that i like this most since it supports collections and does not need to modify it to get the max version.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx) class which lets you compare versions to find the highest.

Eg.

```
List<Version> versions = new List<Version>();
versions.Add(new Version("1.0.1"));
versions.Add(Version("1.0.0"));
versions.Add(Version("2.1.0"));
versions.Add(Version("1.1.0"));
```

Now you can sort the list, and get the highest value:

```
versions.Sort();
var highestVersion = versions.First();
```